# SwiftUI CoreData nillError ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I'm having an issue developing my app. The thing is this, when I enter a certain code, a JSON file starts downloading and got saved in an array. That is fine, the problem is ones it finishes downloading I tried to automatically save the information in CoreData, by running this code below.

```
var i:Int = 0
    while(i < itemsDescargados.count){
    let invitacionItems = Invitem(context: self.mangedObjectContext)
     invitacionItems.titulo = itemsDescargados[i].titulo
     invitacionItems.modo = itemsDescargados[i].modo
     invitacionItems.id = itemsDescargados[i].id
     invitacionItems.descripcion = itemsDescargados[i].descripcion
     invitacionItems.category = itemsDescargados[i].category
     invitacionItems.rojo = itemsDescargados[i].rojo
     invitacionItems.verde = itemsDescargados[i].verde
     invitacionItems.azul = itemsDescargados[i].azul
     invitacionItems.imagen = itemsDescargados[i].imagen

  do {
      try self.mangedObjectContext.save()
      print("Downloaded and Saved!")

    }
    catch{
       print("errorCoreData: \(error)")
     }
     i = i + 1
  }
```

When I put this code into a button and tap it myself it works perfectly, it saves the data and everything is fine, but the problem is that if I run this code into the network manager class `class NetworkManagerInv: ObservableObject {` after the download it's finished then when the app runs `try self.mangedObjectContext.save()` automatically prints in the Console log "errorCoreData:nilError" and doesn't save anything.

I did a lot of research but I didn't find anything helpful so I hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance, sorry if I misspelled something English is not my main language.

Here the NetworkManagerCode

```
class NetworkManagerInv: ObservableObject {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var mangedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Invitem.getAllItems()) var invitem:FetchedResults<Invitem>

var didChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManagerInv, Never>()

var jsoninvItem = [JsoninvItem]() {
    didSet {
        didChange.send(self)
    }
}

init(){

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    print("Network")
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.42:" + codigo + "/items.json") else { return }
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        let items2 = try! JSONDecoder().decode([JsoninvItem].self, from: data)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.jsoninvItem = items2
            itemsDescargados = items2
            if(imgDescargadas.count>0){
                //Here i need to put the code, this runs ones it finished
            }

        }
        print("Compleated fetching json items")

    }.resume()
   }
```